# Ruby Sort_by multiple parameters opposite asc/desc

Tags: ruby, sorting

Trying to sort by multiple parameters but having trouble with one parameter sorting ascendingly and the other descending.

```
array = [20, 10, 40, 1200, 300]
```

I need to first sort the array by the number of digits in each number descending.

So we get `[1200, 120, 40, 10, 20]`

If there is a tie between lengths, I need to sort them ascendingly by value

So we get: `[1200, 120, 10, 20, 40]`

I'm trying to make sort_by work for this but I can't figure out how to sort the first parameter descending and the second ascendingly.

```
def digit_sorter(ar) 
   ar.sort_by {|num| [num.to_s.length, num]}.reverse 
end
```

I've also tried `[ [num.to_s.length], [num].reverse ]`

Comment: Hint: how do you reverse a number? How do you turn a number into its opposite?

Answer (score 5):

```
# length desc, value asc
def digit_sorter(nums)
  nums.sort { |a, b| [b.to_s.length, a] <=> [a.to_s.length, b] }
end


# length asc, value desc
def digit_sorter(nums)
  nums.sort { |a, b| [a.to_s.length, b] <=> [b.to_s.length, a] }
end
```

input same array `[345, 23, 34, 1]`, the output respectively are

```
# length desc, value asc
[345, 23, 34, 1]

# value desc, length asc
[1, 34, 23, 345]
```

Comment: This is a nice general solution as it does not require the objects being sorted to be numbers.

Answer (score 5):

**Always prefer `sort_by` over `sort` when speed may be an issue and `sort` keys are expensive to compute.**
For ascending order, just use the sort key as is, here `a` (value of the array element). For descending order, use `-key` (*minus* key), here `-a.to_s.length` (the length of the array element):

```
array = [20, 10, 40, 1200, 300]
puts array.sort_by { |a| [-a.to_s.length, a] }
```

Prints:

```
1200
300
10
20
40
```

---

**Which is faster: `sort_by` or `sort`?**

> `sort_by` [is] fairly expensive when the keysets are simple. ...
> However, consider the case where comparing the keys is a non-trivial
> operation. A more efficient technique is to cache the `sort` keys ...
> before the `sort`. Perl users often call this approach a Schwartzian
> transform, after Randal Schwartz. ... This is exactly what `sort_by`
> does internally.

(from [`sort_by` docs](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/sort_by))

**SEE ALSO**

[Brandon Dimcheff: "Ruby's sort vs. sort_by"](https://brandon.dimcheff.com/2009/11/18/rubys-sort-vs-sort-by/)

---

**Benchmarking `sort_by` vs. `sort`:**

For the case described by the OP, `sort_by` is slightly faster than `sort`, although both are fast, because the array is small (`size = 5`, see below). As the array grows to more realistic `size=10, 100, 1000`, `sort_by` is about twice as fast, due to the reduced need of the expensive `sort` key computations. Note that relative performance is heavily dependent on the array size and how expensive are the `sort` keys to compute, so treat this as a single data point and do not overgeneralize these results.

**Code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'benchmark' 

max_val = 2_000

[5, 10, 100, 1000].each do |size|
  puts "###"
  puts "array size=#{size}:"
  puts "###"
  Benchmark.bmbm do |x|
    Kernel.srand(1234)
    x.report("sort_by")    { 10000.times { (1..size).to_a.map { rand(max_val) } .sort_by { |a| [-a.to_s.length, a] }  } }
    Kernel.srand(1234)
    x.report("sort") { 10000.times { (1..size).to_a.map { rand(max_val) } .sort { |a, b| [b.to_s.length, a] <=> [a.to_s.length, b] } } } 
  end
end
```

**Results:**

```
###
array size=5:
###
Rehearsal -------------------------------------------
sort_by   0.070000   0.000000   0.070000 (  0.062603)
sort      0.070000   0.000000   0.070000 (  0.074214)
---------------------------------- total: 0.140000sec

              user     system      total        real
sort_by   0.060000   0.000000   0.060000 (  0.061337)
sort      0.070000   0.000000   0.070000 (  0.070706)
###
array size=10:
###
Rehearsal -------------------------------------------
sort_by   0.110000   0.000000   0.110000 (  0.117958)
sort      0.190000   0.000000   0.190000 (  0.183992)
---------------------------------- total: 0.300000sec

              user     system      total        real
sort_by   0.110000   0.000000   0.110000 (  0.116410)
sort      0.180000   0.000000   0.180000 (  0.184045)
###
array size=100:
###
Rehearsal -------------------------------------------
sort_by   1.770000   0.010000   1.780000 (  1.776254)
sort      3.800000   0.000000   3.800000 (  3.797437)
---------------------------------- total: 5.580000sec

              user     system      total        real
sort_by   1.780000   0.000000   1.780000 (  1.783407)
sort      3.860000   0.000000   3.860000 (  3.865884)
###
array size=1000:
###
Rehearsal -------------------------------------------
sort_by  25.380000   0.010000  25.390000 ( 25.403899)
sort     60.290000   0.040000  60.330000 ( 60.374564)
--------------------------------- total: 85.720000sec

              user     system      total        real
sort_by  26.010000   0.060000  26.070000 ( 26.122175)
sort     60.990000   0.060000  61.050000 ( 61.134355)
```